# redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. - PHP

Tags: php, cookies

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['language']) && isset($_COOKIE['page'])) {
    header("Location: index.php?j=".$_COOKIE['language']."&str=".$_COOKIE['page']);}

    if(isset($_COOKIE['language'])) {
    setcookie('language', $_GET['j'], time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
    setcookie('page', $_GET['str'], time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
}
```

When i'm trying to use header as a redirect from page. I got a message

> redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies.

Comment: Is this code on your index.php page? If so you are going to be infinitely redirecting whenever both of your cookies have values.

Comment: You should add `$_GET['j']` and `$_GET['str']`to your conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to redirect if the `j` and `str` parameters are NOT specified.

So when the user visits: `index.php` redirect to `index.php?j=value&str=value`.

But if the users visits: `index.php?j=value&str=value` do not redirect at all.

This is easily accomplished by checking those two parameters are not set before redirecting:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['language']) && isset($_COOKIE['page']) && !isset($_GET['j']) && !isset($_GET['str'])) {
    header("Location: index.php?j=".$_COOKIE['language']."&str=".$_COOKIE['page']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude!